# Ошибка в программе на нахождение минимальной температуры

Tags: python, python-3.x

Найдите минимальную температуру для дней, когда столбик термометра поднимался выше нуля градусов. Определите количество таких дней. Гарантируется, что за время наблюдения хотя бы в один из дней температура поднималась выше нуля градусов.

Программа получает на вход количество дней, в течение которых проводилось наблюдение N (1≤N≤30), затем для каждого дня вводится температура.

```
n = int(input())
q=0
for i in range (0,n):
    w=int(input())
    print(min(w,[if w=>0, q+=1] ) 
    print(q)
```

Comment: Это что за `[if w=>0, q+=1]`? :)

Comment: Я пока что только изучаю питон

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простое решение - в цикле добавлять в список температуру, когда она выше нуля. После цикла в полученном списке уже находим минимальную температуру. Ну и количество дней с положительной температурой равно длине этого списка.

```
n = int(input())
t = []
for i in range(n):
    current_t = int(input())
    if current_t > 0:
        t.append(current_t)

print("Количество дней с положительной температурой:", len(t))
print("Минимальная температура:", min(t))
```

Comment: Все теперь разобрался

Comment: Хотя смотрите надо найти количество дней когда минимальная температура при том что она больше 0, а ваш код находит общее количество дней когда температура больше 0

Comment: @SyntaxError, да. В задании так и написано: найти минимальную температуру для дней (удовлетворяющих условию), и найти количество таких дней (удовлетворяющих условию). Не сказано найти количество дней (удовлетворяющих условию), когда температура была минимальной.